# Okta Okta.Idx.Sdk default RedirectUri

Tags: .net-core, okta

When I run the **embedded-sign-in-widget** sample application in **samples-aspnetcore**, the RedirectUri gets set to “https://localhost:44327/interactioncode/callback”. I know that I can override this by explicitly setting the RedirectUri, but I am trying to understand where this gets set in the sample application. The same URI, including the port, gets set when I implement the sample code in my project. I have served GitHub, the IdxClient source, and the web for this URI, but haven’t been able to locate it.

First, where does the default path of “interactioncode/callback” get set in the SDK’s source? Second, how is the default port determined? (The SDK doesn’t appear to be getting either of these from my client configuration in Okta. I checked.)

My use case is that I am learning. I have no other reason to know where this URI is set, other than I want to understand how the SDK works and the appropriate way to use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what my problem was.  I wasn't seeing a *default* URI.  I forgot that with the Idx SDK gets its configuration from a special file called "okta.yaml" located in "C:\Users{userprfile}.okta".  I had configured this months ago and forgot about it.